Use Azure repository in Google Cloud build as source repository
My code is in an Azure repository. I am using Google Cloud build as CICD. I added clouldbuild.yaml already. But when I try to setup the build trigger, there are only few options available: github, bitbucket etc.
How can I use Azure git repo as the source repository in Google cloud Build?
I don't see any option as a source repository for the Azure git repo in the Google Cloud Build.

I'm surprised to find this not documented. I think (!?) a good way to solve this is to (1) configured WIF for your Azure credentials; (2) Include a cloudbuild.yaml in your repo, it's first step should be to clone the repo; (3) Use Azure pipelines to trigger a call to Cloud Build to run your job.
